# Interpolating time series

Tags: r, xts

I am novice to R but I tried function like merge but it don't work with my data because I have similar times multiple times. I will try to re-clarify my question and hope it will be more clear:

```
library('xts')
library('zoo')
Sys.setenv(TZ='Asia/Calcutta')# setting current time zone to Indian Standard Time
datII=read.table(paste('D:/shankar/R_workspace/MyRWork/data/nwp-II.dat_II.dep',sep=","),head=FALSE,fill = TRUE)
#forecast_time=strptime(as.character(dat[,2]),format='%Y%m%d%H%M',tz="Asia/Calcutta")
base_time=strptime(as.character(dat[,1],dat[,2]),format='%Y%m%d%H%M',tz="Asia/Calcutta")
#approxfun(forecast_time)
dat.xts=xts(dat[,-1],order.by=base_time)`
```

I have a data that is being updated every 6 hours for next eight days at a span of 3 days.
i have coded it as below:

executing dat.xts comes like as below:
I tried to change the second column (v2) also in date format but couldn't succeed.
My problem is I want to extrapolate the series on hourly basis as compared to three hours.
Besides V5 and V6 is not important. Hope I am clear. Thanks in advance.

```
                                              V2     V3     V4 V5 V6
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005010000  1.72 291.38  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005010300  0.95 334.79  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005010600  2.25  57.00  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005010900  0.43  14.73  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005011200  0.75 100.08  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005011500  2.20 149.00  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005011800  1.96 158.75  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005012100  0.94 228.24  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005020000  0.93 270.77  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005020300  1.40 271.91  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005020600  1.55   3.50  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005020900  2.05  63.42  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005021200  2.75 100.32  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005021500  3.83 109.04  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005021800  1.61 149.33  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005022100  1.32 167.59  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005030000  1.74 177.71  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005030300  1.79 192.50  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005030600  0.13  97.95  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005030900  2.15 103.36  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005031200  2.96 110.35  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005031500  2.75 163.97  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005031800  3.16 199.21  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005032100  2.11 223.85  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005040000  1.42 255.40  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005040300  2.37 274.25  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005040600  1.19  18.93  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005040900  1.16  83.48  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005041200  1.65  75.87  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005041500  0.49  86.23  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005041800  1.32 183.03  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005042100  1.04 212.19  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005050000  1.36 279.77  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005050300  2.75 283.78  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005050600  1.20   3.76  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005050900  1.43  86.78  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005051200  1.02 108.71  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005051500  1.10 210.81  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005051800  1.48 239.43  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005052100  1.52 257.16  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005060000  1.26 249.03  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005060300  1.83 271.65  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005060600  0.10 111.22  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005060900  1.33  69.26  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005061200  1.49 130.34  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005061500  1.65 185.87  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005061800  1.99 213.90  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005062100  1.10 223.54  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005070000  1.58 198.25  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005070300  1.97 213.55  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005070600  1.20 199.53  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005070900  1.87 102.46  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005071200  1.89 131.60  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005071500  2.24 195.08  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005071800  1.66 228.50  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005072100  1.84 219.40  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005080000  1.90 210.57  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005080300  2.89 228.87  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005080600  1.38 241.61  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005080900  0.73 171.06  1  0
2010-05-01 00:00:00 201005081200  2.22 199.67  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005010600  1.98  58.86  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005010900  0.54  93.93  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005011200  2.45 128.41  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005011500  2.58 174.05  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005011800  1.65 194.73  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005012100  0.93 256.41  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005020000  1.00 235.41  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005020300  1.94 269.23  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005020600  1.88   2.23  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005020900  1.26  82.13  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005021200  2.10 127.77  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005021500  3.55 123.00  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005021800  1.48 154.10  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005022100  1.33 207.58  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005030000  1.20 218.35  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005030300  1.06 237.34  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005030600  0.99  23.57  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005030900  1.89  91.52  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005031200  3.06 113.00  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005031500  3.55 141.46  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005031800  3.02 200.50  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005032100  2.16 225.42  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005040000  1.49 243.19  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005040300  1.88 285.39  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005040600  1.56  35.71  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005040900  1.85  78.84  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005041200  1.99  96.05  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005041500  0.96 217.58  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005041800  1.74 218.54  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005042100  1.49 238.49  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005050000  1.63 276.95  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005050300  2.63 293.77  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005050600  1.54 338.63  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005050900  1.39  36.10  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005051200  0.63  63.33  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005051500  1.19 178.10  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005051800  2.14 196.01  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005052100  2.24 237.81  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005060000  1.80 273.62  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005060300  2.52 266.71  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005060600  0.91 245.52  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005060900  1.27 149.67  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005061200  2.25 146.56  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005061500  1.63 115.76  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005061800  2.76 204.32  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005062100  1.35 248.81  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005070000  1.21 220.91  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005070300  1.79 236.16  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005070600  0.92 161.52  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005070900  1.83 124.90  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005071200  2.99 153.84  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005071500  2.65 189.17  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005071800  2.20 202.54  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005072100  1.81 195.49  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005080000  1.64 218.71  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005080300  2.44 233.86  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005080600  0.96 194.43  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005080900  1.76 138.89  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005081200  2.79 146.98  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005081500  3.45 226.90  1  0
2010-05-01 06:00:00 201005081800  2.56 263.20  1  0
2010-05-01 12:00:00 201005011200  2.56 148.69  1  0
2010-05-01 12:00:00 201005011500  2.54 172.28  1  0
2010-05-01 12:00:00 201005011800  1.78 195.38  1  0
2010-05-01 12:00:00 201005012100  1.23 259.67  1  0
2010-05-01 12:00:00 201005020000  1.04 237.58  1  0
2010-05-01 12:00:00 201005020300  1.75 265.84  1  0
```

Comment: so: the third column is a string consisting of YEARMONTHDAYHOURMINUTE? If so, it may be simplest just to use string functions to extract the HOURMINUTE part.  Or you could look thru the `lubridate` package for some helpful functions.

Comment: don't know what you exactly want but maybe you can find some information in this Stackexchange question: [http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12980/subset-data-by-month-in-r/12992#12992](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12980/subset-data-by-month-in-r/12992#12992)

Comment: There is no question here. What are you trying to do, and what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

The data portion of an xts object needs to be a matrix. A matrix needs to have all of its elements of the same atomic mode: one and only one of "numeric", "character", "logical". The time index needs to be something that can be ordered. I don't know how you got an xts object whose index was constant. That shouldn't be possible.

You seem to have picked the wrong columns to convert to the time-index. What you really want (assuming your goal is to create an xts object) is to start over again and apply the `strptime` conversion to what you now see as "V2".